# I can show as a column with a join? Symfony Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have two separate tables, one called "Projects" and one called "tasks" each is in a different Bundle. Within each task I want to relate to a project. To do this I created the corresponding entity in the corresponding Bundle as follows:

The idProyecto field of the Entity Tasks I want to relate to the id field of the Entity Projects

**/src/Panel/TasksBundle/Entity/Tasks;**

```
/**
 * @var \Projects
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Panel\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Projects", inversedBy="Tareas")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proyecto", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idProyecto;
```

**/src/Panel/ProjectsBundle/Entity/Projects;**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="id", mappedBy="Proyectos")
 */
private $id;
```

**Twig**

```
{% for key, t in tasks %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ t.projects.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.descripcion }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.fechaIni | date("d/m/Y") }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.fechaFin | date("d/m/Y") }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tasks", mappedBy="idProyecto")`

Comment: you need to read [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)